# SQL windowing and continuously using filters to pass threshold

Tags: sql, sql-function

I don't know if I'm explaining this properly but I'm in a bit of a dilemma. I'm currently trying to figure out how to do something within SQL, while also keeping it relatively clean.

Say, that I want to give out awards to the top 5 players on each team in a basketball league. I'll first start with one filter to help determine who the top 5 players are. I don't mind picking the top 5 players for each team based on a single filter. I will first check for players on each team that have scored over 20 points in the season.

```
create table teams1
as 
select
name,
team,
row_number() over (partition by team order by points desc)  as rank
from teams
where rank <= 5
and points >= 20;
```

In this case, some teams might have filled their top 5 slots with players who have all scored over 20 points. But other teams might have one person with over 20 points and still have slots left on their teams. This is where it gets tricky for me. What if I want to go through the data again with a filter that is trying to fill those remaining spots without looking at teams that are already filled. Would I do something along the lines of..

```
create table teams2
as 
select
name,
team,
row_number() over (parition by team order by rebounds desc) as rank
from teams
where rank <= 5
and rebounds >= 10
and team not in (
select team from (
select team, count(*)  as player_count
from teams1
group by team
having player_count >= 5));
```

In this case, I'm checking the previous table for teams that are already filled by doing the subquery and checking for teams with counts over greater than or equal to 5 but how do I make sure I'm only pulling the number of players I want to pull rather than pulling 5 more players that fit the rebound criteria onto a team that already has 2 players. I was thinking of maybe incorporating a column into the data that checks the count in previous tables of how many players are already on a team and possibly subtracting it from 5 so I'm only going up to the number I need for each one when selecting the ranks. Sorry if this is confusing but I tried the best I could to explain it and not make it boring.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in on `row_number()`, just by adjusting the `order by`:

```
select name, team, seqnum
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by team 
                                order by (case when points >= 20 then points else 0 end) desc,
                                         rebounds desc
                               )  as seqnum
      from teams t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 5;
```

This fills the five slots right away.  Players with a score above 20 are sorted first.  Those with a lower score all go in the "0" score bin.  The rebounds are then used, primarily for that group.

The one caveat is that when you have ties among high scorers, the tie is broken by the number of rebounds.  I actually think that is a feature of this solution rather than a drawback.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Say a few teams don't get filled after the rebounds check, could I do something like, ...desc, (case when rebounds >= 10 then rebounds else 0 end) desc, steals desc) as seqnum... ?

Comment: @SeaJay . . . You can add more keys.  But you are missing the point of the logic.  This will always return 5 players (assuming there are five players).  The five players are based on the sorting logic in the `row_number()` function.

Comment: So let me see if I understand incorrectly. You're ordering it by the case statement that checks whether the points are above 20 or not and giving a zero if they aren't, which is the lowest a player could possibly get and disqualifies them from the the first one. It will then take the players that got 0 during the points check and order and rank based on rebounds. Those with 0 as points but the highest rebounds will be considered for the rank where the first check left off? If this part is correct and we still weren't able to fill every team after those two checks, could we use steals desc

Comment: @SeaJay . . . You are correct, but just missing the part that there is no filtering.  You can add `steals desc` to the sort key to handle the cases where points are less than 20 and rebounds are 0.

Comment: as the final check with an added filter on it, like steals >= 3? At this point, I would feel players that don't fit the three criteria won't be considered as a top player and some teams will just not be able to reach 5 players. I'm less interested in filling out the team and more interested in seeing if players fit a certain criteria on each team then limiting the number of players that can be top players on a team. One team might have 10 players that fit the criteria to be a top player based on the standard but I only want the top 5 and other teams might have one one player that fits and

Comment: @SeaJay . . . Then add something like `steals > 0 and points > 5` or whatever in a `where` clause to eliminate players that are out of consideration entirely.

Comment: I'm willing to only take that  one player as no one else on the team fits the criteria. Sorry, if this is long winded and confusing. I'm working on getting better at asking questions and describing my problems :)

Comment: Ooooh ok got it. So no matter what, it will take into account those with 0 since the goal is trying to reach five players on the team.